# $\text{rank}(A - I) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a square matrix with real entries, does $\text{rank}(A-I)=0$ tell me that $A=I$? Since the zero matrix is the only matrix of rank zero? ($I$ is the corresponding identity matrix).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that's correct, indeed we have that $\forall x$, $x$ is in the null space of $(A-I)$ that is

$$(A-I)x=0 \iff Ax=x \iff A=I$$

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does. And this is extra text to satisfy the 30-character lower limit on answers.

Comment: +1 for the satisfaction ;)